# OpenProject Docker Error: Could not spawn process for application /app

Tags: openproject

Upgraded the community edition of OpenProject from a working 9.0.3 version to "latest" (10.0.2?) in Docker and now getting the following error when trying to navigate to OpenProject (seeing the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." page)

Log is below, but looks like error may be:

```
[ E 2019-10-10 01:02:17.7066 370/Tc age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /app: A timeout occurred while starting a preloader process.
```

Not sure where to start on troubleshooting this...

```
[ N 2019-10-10 01:00:38.4197 370/T5 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:519 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
Forcefully loading the application. Use :environment to avoid eager loading.
hook registered
App 402 output: hook registered
Creating scope :order_by_name. Overwriting existing method Sprint.order_by_name.
App 402 output: Creating scope :order_by_name. Overwriting existing method Sprint.order_by_name.
2019-10-10 01:02:16.042 UTC [440] openproject@openproject LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
[ E 2019-10-10 01:02:17.7066 370/Tc age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /app: A timeout occurred while starting a preloader process.
  Error ID: 89e9b405
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-1pJJ4k.html

[ E 2019-10-10 01:02:17.7223 370/T7 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 1-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 89e9b405. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[ E 2019-10-10 01:02:17.8692 370/T7 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 1-2] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 89e9b405. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[Worker(host:8416036a7682 pid:135)] Starting job worker
2019-10-10T01:03:17+0000: [Worker(host:8416036a7682 pid:135)] Starting job worker
App 459 output: hook registered
App 459 output: Creating scope :order_by_name. Overwriting existing method Sprint.order_by_name.
[ E 2019-10-10 01:05:00.6208 370/Th age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /app: A timeout occurred while starting a preloader process.
  Error ID: c22d62f4
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-8jCQPq.html

[ E 2019-10-10 01:05:00.6559 370/T7 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 1-3] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is c22d62f4. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

Comment: have you tried taking a look at the error details noted in the log file (e.g. `Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-8jCQPq.html`)?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Same, looking for the solution. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem can be solved by increasing the PassengerStartTimeout from 90 (Default) to 200.

I done it by adding the line

```
PassengerStartTimeout 200
```

to the /opt/openproject-10.3.1-1/apache2/conf/bitnami/passenger.conf

and restarted apache server

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In openproject Docker image, add `PASSENGER_START_TIMEOUT=200` to environment variable.

```
docker run -d -e PASSENGER_START_TIMEOUT=200 ...add any options... openproject/community:10
```

This works for me.